# Get the object of the centered element in a slider

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have to display somewhere in the page a field of an object that I dinamically transmit to a slider. It should always be the object that is in the center of the slider.

I am using vue-awesome-slider. Until now i have the following code:

```
<v-layout>
      <v-flex xs4>
        <div >
          <p v-html="previewArtefact"></p>
        </div>
      </v-flex>
      <v-flex xs8>
        <swiper class="" :options="swiperOption" >

        <swiper-slide v-for="(artefact,i) in artefacts" :key="i" v-if="i<5">
            <web-artefact-card  :artefact='artefact'></web-artefact-card>
        </swiper-slide> 

        <div class="swiper-pagination " slot="pagination"></div>
        <div class="swiper-button-prev" slot="button-prev"></div>
        <div class="swiper-button-next" slot="button-next"></div>

        </swiper>
      </v-flex>
</v-layout>
```

And :

```
data() {
return {
  previewArtefact:
    '<i style="padding-left:10%">The text of the artefact...</i>',
  swiperOption: {
    slidesPerView: 3,
    spaceBetween: 30,
    centeredSlides: true,
    pagination: {
      el: ".swiper-pagination",
      clickable: true
    },
    navigation: {
      nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
      prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev"
    }
  }
};
```

The slide in the center always gets a class '.swiper-slide-active', but I don't know now I could get to the object from that. 'prewiewArtefact' should contain artefact.text .

Comment: A directive that checks its classList on update could emit an event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Phew that was hard :D, okay here is an example worked for me, I couldn't find better ways

```
<template>
 <div>
 <swiper :options="swiperOption" ref="mySwiperA">
  <!-- slides -->
  <swiper-slide>I'm Slide 1</swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide>I'm Slide 2</swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide>I'm Slide 3</swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide>I'm Slide 4</swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide>I'm Slide 5</swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide>I'm Slide 6</swiper-slide>
  <swiper-slide>I'm Slide 7</swiper-slide>

 </swiper>

 <p>{{ swiper ? swiper.activeIndex : '' }}</p>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
 export default {
  data(){
   return {
    swiperOption:{
     slidesPerView: 3,
     centeredSlides: true,
     pagination: {
      el: ".swiper-pagination",
      clickable: true
     },
     navigation: {
      nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
      prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev"
     }
    },
    swiper: null
  }
 },
 mounted(){
  this.swiper = this.$refs.mySwiperA.swiper
 }
}
</script>
```

Simply when the vue gets mounted you need to set `this.swiper` to `this.$refs.{swiper ref}.swiper` then you can get the active index by calling `this.swiper.activeIndex`

Comment: I think `this.swiper.realIndex` is better than `this.swiper.activeIndex`.